# Swift gives me an error message in console for println

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I started to learn swift same as using MAC_OS, here is what playground says when i try to "println" any string. I understand it's beta, but still may be somebody already resolved this problem. Thank you.

**Unable to create symlink at /Users/macbook/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.practice-6F0906B2-660F-40C1-A655-7882D32383CF/Data/Documents/Shared Playground Data due to error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "The file “Shared Playground Data” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Documents” because a file with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x7f9ce2504340 {NSFilePath=/Users/macbook/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.practice-6F0906B2-660F-40C1-A655-7882D32383CF/Data/Documents/Shared Playground Data, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9ce2503d40 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"})**

Answer (score 1):

Quit Xcode and delete

`/Users/macbook/Library/Containers/com.apple.dt.playground.stub.OSX.practice-6F0906B2-660F-40C1-A655-7882D32383CF/`

Then try running your playground again.